# Executing .COM file with specified parameters

Tags: assembly, dos

I am trying to execute .com file with specified arguments under MS-DOS 6.

I've found DOS 2+ - EXEC - LOAD AND/OR EXECUTE PROGRAM Int 21/AH=4Bh
The problem is, I don't know how exactly should I pass these parameters.
ES:BX should contain something called 'parameter block', but how to construct it? If i'd want to for example execute file named command.com with arguments `/C ECHO HELLO WORLD`, how would I call this interrupt?

Code that I already have:

```
ORG 100H
START:
    MOV AH, 4BH ;AH=>4BH
    XOR AL, AL  ;AL=>00H
    MOV DX, CMD ;DS:DX=>STRING
    MOV BX, PARAM;ES:BX=>PARAMS
    INT 21H
    MOV AH,4CH
    INT 21H
CMD: DB "COMMAND.COM$" ;NOT SURE, SHOULD END WITH $
PARAM: ;???
```

How do i make my program do task mentioned earlier? As MS-DOS is nearly dead, and my assembler, NASM, is barely supported on this platform, I'm going to have bad time. My code may be poorly written as there are no resources about DOS.

Whole point of it is executing batch file generated on runtime by program.

Comment: What documentation are you using? I would use Ralf Brown's Interrupt List. It answers your questions. http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs.cmu.edu/user/ralf/pub/WWW/ralf-home.html is Ralf's own page.  http://www.ctyme.com/rbrown.htm is another  place to find it.

Comment: I've used it, without luck. ' DOS 2+ - EXEC - LOAD AND/OR EXECUTE PROGRAM Int 21/AH=4Bh' is clear CTRL+C & CTRL+V from RBIL

Comment: It says the program name is null-terminated and it gives the layout of the parameter block. What's missing?

Comment: I have to wonder why you're writing 16-bit DOS programs at all.  Learning the DOS system-call interface seems like a total waste of time to me.  But I guess you enjoy retro-computing.  NASM should be totally fine for generating `.com` executables where all you need is a flat binary.  Or is the "barely supported" comment about building a NASM executable that runs under 16-bit DOS?

Comment: You may want to do a search and download for masm 6.11, which is Microsoft's assembler. If running from MSDOS (or real mode) you'll need to set an environment variable: `set tnt=-nopspgrow`, which is used by Microsoft tool set to run it's 32 bit based tools in 16 bit real mode.

Answer (score 5):

> `CMD: DB "COMMAND.COM$" ;NOT SURE, SHOULD END WITH $`

The only function that requires a string to end with `$` is function 9 (print string). Most other functions require a string to end with `NUL` (which is the byte with the value 0 - not the ASCII digit `'0'`).

Just like this:

```
CMD DB "COMMAND.COM"
    DB 0
```

The next problem you have is that a COM file gets nearly all available memory when being started.

Function `04Bh` will fail because there is not enough memory (because all the memory is "used" by the .COM file).

You have to use function `04Ah` to resize the memory block used by the .COM file before calling function `4Bh`:

```
push cs  ; Only needed if ES != CS
pop  es  ; ...
mov  bx, 1000h
mov  ah, 4Ah
int  21h
```

> `PARAM: ;???`

According to Ralph Brown's interrupt list this is 14 bytes long:

- The segment containing the environment (or 0 to copy the environment) (2 bytes)
- A pointer (offset, segment) to the command line (4 bytes)
- A pointer (offset, segment) to the first FCB (4 bytes)
- A pointer (offset, segment) to the second FCB (4 bytes)

AFAIK the first byte of the command line is the number of bytes following, followed by the actual letters followed by the byte `0Dh`. (Check the content of `cs:80h` to check this information.)

The FCBs are special representations of the first two command line arguments needed for DOS 1.x programs. Because they are not needed any more since DOS 2.x you can simply pass two dummy FCBs here. FCBs are 16 bytes long. You can simply "copy" the FCBs from your program (`cs:05Ch` and `cs:06Ch`) to the control block:

```
PARAM:
    DW   0
    DW   CMDLINE
    DW   ???      ; Write CS here
    DW   05Ch
    DW   ???      ; Write CS here
    DW   06Ch
    DW   ???      ; Write CS here
CMDLINE:
    DB   xxx      ; Replace by the length of the command line
    DB   "xxx"    ; Replace by the actul command line
    DB   0Dh      ; Note: Not 0 but 0Dh in this case
```

Comment: The stack needs to be relocated before releasing memory. Once command line parameters are handled, the stack pointer could be set to 00100h.

Comment: @rcgldr The stack is located somewhere near `CS:0FFFFh` in a COM file. When releasing the memory to a size of `1000h` paragraphs (`10000h` bytes) the stack would still be inside the allocated memory.

Comment: Unless within 64k of the end of main memory (usually 640k boundary), the stack pointer is set to zero and a push with value zero is done, resulting in SP = 0FFFEh. However, more memory could be released by setting SP to a lower value (or 00100h before the code), and setting BX = (end of code + 15)>>4 on the memory release.

Comment: what does 'DW   ???      ; Write CS here' mean? What should i place instead of question marks?

Comment: @KrzysztofSzewczyk You may write any value here; the value of the `CS` register must be written to this location. Because the value of the `CS` register cannot be "predicted" at compile time you'll have to overwrite this value in any case.

Comment: ain't cs=100h or so? I may be wrong as theres so little amount of resourcesa available to me

Comment: @KrzysztofSzewczyk No. The "absolute" (linear) starting address is `10h * CS + 100h`. At least on real MS-DOS the "linear starting address" depends on the memory used by the OS (e.g. which device drivers are loaded). So `CS` differs depending on the memory used by the OS.

Comment: @KrzysztofSzewczyk - for the dw ???, you can use `dw 0` or `dw ?` or `dw 1 dup (?)`. For a .COM program, might as well use `dw 0`. On MSDOS 6.22, running on a virtual PC, the lowest I get is cs = 0064Bh (sp = 0fffeh), and using a program to allocate most of memory, the highest I get is cs = 09fd7h (sp = 0027eh). The theoretical max for a .com program <= 16 bytes in size would be cs = 09fdfh (sp = 0020eh).